# How to write Rails architecture for presentation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture

This is a general question, but for example, I have a deployable Rails app already and I want to deliver my product to clients, what kind of architecture should I be displaying in my presentation?

Comment: I suppose you mean what platform you should deploy it on? Heroku is free and easy to deploy too. The only thing is that you'll end up having "herokuapp" as a part of your domain name. A google domain isn't that difficult to set up but you'll have to link it to your heroku app though a google domain is not free. Also, you'll probably receive more downvotes on this question because this is really an open ended question - opinion based answers. Just a heads up.